# can not pass and retrive parameter value when calling an aspx file using jquery ajax;

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

### Jquery code:

```
$('#sendmessage').click(function () {
  var data1 = $('#message').val();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "NotificationTest.aspx/OnSubmit",
    data:'{name:'+data1+'}',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      alert("Request: " + XMLHttpRequest.toString() + "\n\nStatus: " + 
        textStatus + "\n\nError: " + errorThrown);
    },
    success: function (result) {
      // alert("We returned: " + result);
      $("#noti_Button").val(result); *** here can not catch value***
    }
  });
});
```

C# code:
     here is my c# code to getting value from jquery and return again.
       string is not returned or other thing i ca not underatand.

```
  [WebMethod]
public  static string OnSubmit(string name)
{
  return name;
}
```

ERRor:Internal server error.

Comment: Do not build JSON by hand

Comment: What is not working?, and also in your `success:` you cant access `result.d.n` when your C# is returning a plain String.

Comment: getting error in console? Also make onsubmit method as static.

Comment: Your JSON in invalid as the string wont be surrounded by quotes, and as @N.Ivanov stated, you wont access `result.d.name`, but simply `result`

Answer (score 0):

Make your method static:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string OnSubmit(string name)
{
  return name;
}
```